# Converting time zone pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have data:

```
                             Symbol      bid      ask
Timestamp                                            
2014-01-01 21:55:34.378000  EUR/USD  1.37622  1.37693
2014-01-01 21:55:40.410000  EUR/USD  1.37624  1.37698
2014-01-01 21:55:47.210000  EUR/USD  1.37619  1.37696
2014-01-01 21:55:57.963000  EUR/USD  1.37616  1.37696
2014-01-01 21:56:03.117000  EUR/USD  1.37616  1.37694
```

The timestamp is in GMT. Is there a way to convert that to Eastern?

Note when I do:

```
data.index
```

I get output:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-01-01 21:55:34.378000, ..., 2014-01-01 21:56:03.117000]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Localize the index (using `tz_localize`) to UTC (to make the Timestamps timezone-aware) and then convert to Eastern (using `tz_convert`):

```
import pytz
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(pytz.utc).tz_convert(eastern)
```

---

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz

index = pd.date_range('20140101 21:55', freq='15S', periods=5)
df = pd.DataFrame(1, index=index, columns=['X'])
print(df)
#                      X
# 2014-01-01 21:55:00  1
# 2014-01-01 21:55:15  1
# 2014-01-01 21:55:30  1
# 2014-01-01 21:55:45  1
# 2014-01-01 21:56:00  1

# [5 rows x 1 columns]
print(df.index)
# <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
# [2014-01-01 21:55:00, ..., 2014-01-01 21:56:00]
# Length: 5, Freq: 15S, Timezone: None

eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(pytz.utc).tz_convert(eastern)
print(df)
#                            X
# 2014-01-01 16:55:00-05:00  1
# 2014-01-01 16:55:15-05:00  1
# 2014-01-01 16:55:30-05:00  1
# 2014-01-01 16:55:45-05:00  1
# 2014-01-01 16:56:00-05:00  1

# [5 rows x 1 columns]

print(df.index)
# <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
# [2014-01-01 16:55:00-05:00, ..., 2014-01-01 16:56:00-05:00]
# Length: 5, Freq: 15S, Timezone: US/Eastern
```

Comment: My datetimes are in the column called "date", so I'm doing `df.date = df['date'].pytz_localize(pytz.utc).pytz_convert(pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam'))`, but I get `TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex`.  Why does the error mention "index" when I do not?  Does this only work if the datetime is in the df index?

Comment: @AstroFloyd --- see the thread below for your answer (I had same problem):
This also works similarly for datetime columns, but you need dt after accessing the column:
df['column'] = df['column'].dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')

Comment: If `pandas` is to drop pytz at some point in the future, better omit that part in the code *now*. Just e.g. `df.index.tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert("America/New_York")`

Answer (score 49):

The simplest way is to use `to_datetime` with `utc=True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol': ['EUR/USD'] * 5,
                  'bid': [1.37622, 1.37624, 1.37619, 1.37616, 1.37616],
                  'ask': [1.37693, 1.37698, 1.37696, 1.37696, 1.37694]})

df.index = pd.to_datetime(['2014-01-01 21:55:34.378000',
                          '2014-01-01 21:55:40.410000',
                          '2014-01-01 21:55:47.210000',
                          '2014-01-01 21:55:57.963000',
                          '2014-01-01 21:56:03.117000'],
                           utc=True)
```

For more flexibility, you can convert timezones with [`tz_convert()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html).  If your data column/index is not timezone-aware, you will get a warning, and should first make the data timezone-aware with [`tz_localize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol': ['EUR/USD'] * 5,
                  'bid': [1.37622, 1.37624, 1.37619, 1.37616, 1.37616],
                  'ask': [1.37693, 1.37698, 1.37696, 1.37696, 1.37694]})

df.index = pd.to_datetime(['2014-01-01 21:55:34.378000',
                          '2014-01-01 21:55:40.410000',
                          '2014-01-01 21:55:47.210000',
                          '2014-01-01 21:55:57.963000',
                          '2014-01-01 21:56:03.117000'])

df.index = df.index.tz_localize('GMT')
df.index = df.index.tz_convert('America/New_York')
```

This also works similarly for datetime columns, but you need `dt` after accessing the column:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')
```

Comment: and if your column is not an index, you can do: `df['time_local'] = df['time'].dt.tz_localize('GMT').dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')`

Comment: For me simply writing `...dt.tz_convert('Asia/Singapore')` didn't work, I got strange times. I had to do `...dt.tz_convert(pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore'))`

Comment: no need to localize to `GMT`; just parse the timestamps with kwarg `utc=True` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime)).

Comment: Does this procedure (tc_localize & tc_convert) Also take into account the jungle that is DST?

Comment: Pretty sure yes but someone should confirm

Comment: In response to the comment-question by @Psychotechnopath, I just tested it out for 2020 and 2021 and it correctly captured the DST changes for EST.

Comment: @Psychotechnopath It depends on the timezone used. If you use GMT, no as GMT is a fixed timezone, but if you use one of the location based labels then it s figured out as appropriate, eg 'Europe/London' includes daylight savings for all years after 1911 (or whenever British Summer Time was introduced)

Answer (score 6):

To convert EST time into Asia tz

```
df.index = data.index.tz_localize('EST')
df.index = data.index.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')
```

Pandas has now inbuilt tz conversion ability.

Comment: Thanks @Shivendra.

Comment: note [this comment](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/846c3ac7abc246094dd754ac6dc90423148a5107/northamerica#L188) on `EST` - better use `US/Eastern` or `America/New_York` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd 

# Import pytz
import pytz

# If the column is not the index
# Assuming the column is in UTC or GMT times
# Convert to your desired time zone and remove the time zone information after conversion

df_1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['time'], unit='s', utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Europe/Paris').dt.tz_localize(None)

# To create a separate column with only the date values and without time
df_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['time']).dt.normalize()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).