# How to convert time zone of datetime column in pandas, then remove time zone?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, datetime-format

I have a column (non-index column) that has datetimes inside it. For example, the first five entries look something like this:

```
[Timestamp('2018-11-15 19:57:55'),
 Timestamp('2018-11-15 19:59:46'),
 Timestamp('2018-11-15 20:00:59'),
 Timestamp('2018-11-15 20:01:41'),
 Timestamp('2018-11-15 20:01:54')]
```

I want to convert the entries from UTC to the Pacific timezone. Assuming the column is called `times` I am currently doing the following:

`times.dt.tz_localize('GMT').dt.tz_convert('America/Los_Angeles')`

While this successfully converts the column from UTC to PST, the output has extraneous components that I do not want. It looks like the following:

```
[Timestamp('2018-11-15 11:57:55-0800', tz='America/Los_Angeles'),
 Timestamp('2018-11-15 11:59:46-0800', tz='America/Los_Angeles'),
 Timestamp('2018-11-15 12:00:59-0800', tz='America/Los_Angeles'),
 Timestamp('2018-11-15 12:01:41-0800', tz='America/Los_Angeles'),
 Timestamp('2018-11-15 12:01:54-0800', tz='America/Los_Angeles')]
```

How do I remove or ignore the `-0800` from the timestamps? Thanks!

Comment: I looked at that, but their output was in the form `16:56:00-05:00`, similar to the issue I brought up. I don't know what they `05:00` represents or why that happens, but I don't want that in my output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting time zone pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800079/converting-time-zone-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just add a last step of `.tz_localize(None)`:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.Series(['2018-11-15 19:57:55', '2018-11-15 19:59:46'])
d = pd.to_datetime(d)
d
0   2018-11-15 19:57:55
1   2018-11-15 19:59:46
dtype: datetime64[ns]

d_pacific_tz_aware = d.dt.tz_localize("GMT").dt.tz_convert('America/Los_Angeles')
d_pacific_tz_aware
0   2018-11-15 11:57:55-08:00
1   2018-11-15 11:59:46-08:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, America/Los_Angeles]


d_pacific_tz_naive = d.dt.tz_localize("GMT").dt.tz_convert('America/Los_Angeles').dt.tz_localize(None)
d_pacific_tz_naive
0   2018-11-15 11:57:55
1   2018-11-15 11:59:46
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```