# Combine datetime and timezone columns in a Pandas DataFrame (tz_localize from column)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, pytz

As already answered ([Converting time zone pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800079/converting-time-zone-pandas-dataframe)), Pandas provides means to localize `datetime` columns (`tz_localize`) and convert time zones (`tz_convert`) to a predefined time zone. For example:

```
df["localized_time"] = df.time.tz_localize(pytz.utc).tz_convert("Some/Timezone")
```

However, both functions accept the time zone itself as an argument. What if the time zone comes from another column in the same data frame? For example:

```
   time                 timezone        ...
0  2022-04-11 12:24:43  "Europe/Paris"  ...
1  2022-04-11 04:22:12  "US/Eastern"    ...
...
```

Is there a simple way to combine the "time" column (already a `datetime` type) with the time zone taken the "timezone" column (string)?

Comment: btw. you don't need to import pytz; you can do `.tz_localize("UTC")` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, e.g. by:

```
df["localized_time"] = df.time.dt.tz_localize(pytz.utc)

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["localized_time"].tz_convert(x["timezone"]), 1)
print (df)
                 time      timezone            localized_time  \
0 2022-04-11 12:24:43  Europe/Paris 2022-04-11 12:24:43+00:00   
1 2022-04-11 04:22:12    US/Eastern 2022-04-11 04:22:12+00:00   

                         new  
0  2022-04-11 14:24:43+02:00  
1  2022-04-11 00:22:12-04:00
```

But because there are different timezones get `object`s instead `datetimes` dtype:

```
print (df.dtypes)
time                   datetime64[ns]
timezone                       object
localized_time    datetime64[ns, UTC]
new                            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that timezone info is a part of the type itself. Thank you.