# Python snscrape: How to scrape tweet URL/link using snscrape?

Tags: python

What parameter should we use to include the URL/link of tweets? I have here the date, username, and content. Another question also is how can we transform the date in the dataframe into GMT+8? The timezone is in UTC. Please see code below for reference:

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd

query = "(from:elonmusk) until:2023-01-28 since:2023-01-27"
tweets = []
limit = 100000


for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():
    
    if len(tweets) == limit:
        break
    else:
        tweets.append([tweet.date, tweet.username, tweet.content])
        
df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['Date', 'Username', 'Tweet'])

#Save to csv
df.to_csv('tweets.csv')
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_items()` return every single a search result with class type.
So the count of tweets needs to count by for loop.

#### This code will works

100K tweets is possible but it take too much time, I reduced 1K tweets.

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd

query = 'from:elonmusk since:2022-08-01 until:2023-01-28'
limit = 1000

tweets = sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items()

index = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','URL' ,'Tweet'])

for tweet in tweets:
    if index == limit:
        break
    URL = "https://twitter.com/{0}/status/{1}".format(tweet.user.username,tweet.id)
    df2 = {'Date': tweet.date, 'URL': URL, 'Tweet': tweet.rawContent}
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records([df2])])
    index = index + 1

# # Converting time zone from UTC to GMT+8
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.tz_convert('Etc/GMT+8')
print(df)

df.to_csv('tweets.csv')
```

This single data of get_items()
it needs to extract only required key's value

```
tweet.date -> Date

https://twitter.com/tweet.user.username/status/tweet.id-> URL

tweet.rawContent-> Tweet
```

```
{
  "_type": "snscrape.modules.twitter.Tweet",
  "url": "https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1619164489710178307",
  "date": "2023-01-28T02:44:31+00:00",
  "rawContent": "@tn_daki @ShitpostGate Yup",
  "renderedContent": "@tn_daki @ShitpostGate Yup",
  "id": 1619164489710178307,
  "user": {
    "_type": "snscrape.modules.twitter.User",
    "username": "elonmusk",
    "id": 44196397,
    "displayname": "Mr. Tweet",
    "rawDescription": "",
    "renderedDescription": "",
    "descriptionLinks": null,
    "verified": true,
    "created": "2009-06-02T20:12:29+00:00",
    "followersCount": 127536699,
    "friendsCount": 176,
    "statusesCount": 22411,
    "favouritesCount": 17500,
    "listedCount": 113687,
    "mediaCount": 1367,
    "location": "",
    "protected": false,
    "link": null,
    "profileImageUrl": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1590968738358079488/IY9Gx6Ok_normal.jpg",
    "profileBannerUrl": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/44196397/1576183471",
    "label": null,
    "url": "https://twitter.com/elonmusk"
  }
    ... cut off
```

#### Result

```
>python get-data.py
                        Date                                                URL                                              Tweet
0  2023-01-27 15:29:36-08:00  https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1619115435...                                  @farzyness No way
0  2023-01-27 15:14:05-08:00  https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1619111533...  @mtaibbi Please correct your bs @PolitiFact &a...
0  2023-01-27 14:52:55-08:00  https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1619106207...  @WallStreetSilv A quarter of all taxes just to...
0  2023-01-27 13:28:26-08:00  https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1619084945...           @nudubabba @mikeduncan Yeah, whole thing
0  2023-01-27 13:12:16-08:00  https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1619080876...  @TaraBull808 That’s way more monkeys than the ...
..                       ...                                                ...                                                ...
0  2022-12-14 11:14:53-08:00  https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1603106271...  @Jason Advertising revenue next year will be l...
0  2022-12-14 04:08:43-08:00  https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1602999020...                        @Balyx_ He would be welcome
0  2022-12-14 03:42:47-08:00  https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1602992493...  @NorwayMFA @TwitterSupport @jonasgahrstore @AH...
0  2022-12-14 03:35:14-08:00  https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1602990594...                                    @AvidHalaby Wow
0  2022-12-14 03:35:03-08:00  https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1602990549...                     @AvidHalaby Live &amp; learn …

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```

#### Reference

[Converting time zone pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800079/converting-time-zone-pandas-dataframe)

#### Tweet URL format

Detain information in [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/blog/community/2020/getting-to-the-canonical-url-for-a-tweet)

Example:

URL = "https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1619111533216403456"

It saved into csv file.

```
0,2023-01-27 15:14:05-08:00,https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1619111533216403456,@mtaibbi Please correct your bs @PolitiFact &amp; @snopes
```

It matched the tweet content and pandas `Tweet` column.

Also, you can add column, `followers Count`, `friends Count`, `statuses Count`, `favourites Count`, `listed Count`, `media Count`, `reply Count`,  `retweet Count`, `like Count` and `view Count` too.

[image]

Comment: Bue thanks for this! is it possible to extract the link or url of tweets? Thanks again

Comment: I updated to add URL and many other variable also possible.